# I am not able to create arrays in Nes-C language. any suggestions ?

Tags: arrays, tinyos

Can anyone tell me how to create arrays in nes-c. Also i would like to print them. I just saw on google that this is a way but its giving me errors.
uint8_t i;*

> *uint8_t in[16] = 
>   {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};*

Comment: The approach `uint8_t in[16] = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};` will work, but I see `uint8_t i;*` before in your code. What is this `*` for? It will definitely cause an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late to the party, but maybe it's still useful to answer this.

**Creating an array**

Arrays in nesC are defined the same way as in normal C language, since nesC is simply an extension of C:

```
type arrayName [ arraySize ];
```

I use [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm) for concise tutorials on C, but you can find explanations on a multitude of websites. In your case I would define the array like this:

```
uint8_t in[16];
```

Initializing the array with zeroes is best done with the command memset:

```
memset(in, 0, sizeof(in));
```

Why? It's clean code, works efficiently, and doesn't need adjusting when you decide to increase the size of the array.

**Printing an array**

For this I'll refer you to the [TinyOS Printf Library tutorial](http://tinyos.stanford.edu/tinyos-wiki/index.php/The_TinyOS_printf_Library), this explains how you print stuff to the console in TinyOS. I assume you're working with this since you're asking a nesC question.

Printing an array can be done through a simple for-loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(in); ++i) {
  printf("%u", in[i]);
}
printfflush();
```

Good luck!